# Default arguments for member function of templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, default-arguments

Let's say I have something like this bit of (duplicated) code that I'd like to refactor using a template:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

struct IntFoo {
  auto f(int arg, std::set<int> s = {1, 2, 3}) {
    return std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), arg) != s.end();
  }
};

struct FloatFoo {
  auto f(float arg, std::set<float> s = {4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f}) {
    return std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), arg) != s.end();
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << IntFoo().f(3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << FloatFoo().f(4.0f) << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see, beyond the variance in type there is also the change in the default arguments given to `f()`'s second parameter.

Best I could come up with was this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

template<typename T, typename Def>
struct Foo {
  auto f(T arg, std::set<T> s = Def::defaults){
    return std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), arg) != s.end();
  }
};

struct FooIntDefaults {
  static constexpr std::initializer_list<int> defaults{1, 2, 3};
};

struct FooFloatDefaults {
  static constexpr std::initializer_list<float> defaults{4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f};
};

using IntFoo = Foo<int, FooIntDefaults>;
using FloatFoo = Foo<float, FooFloatDefaults>;
```

This works, but is a bit verbose.  I don't fancy these helper structs much.

Ideally I'd like to pass the default arguments in the `using` line somehow.  Is there some better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for specifying default arguments, e.g.

```
template<typename T, T... defaults>
struct Foo {
  auto f(T arg, std::set<T> s = {defaults...}){
    return std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), arg) != s.end();
  }
};

using IntFoo = Foo<int, 1, 2, 3>;              // specify default arguments when defining type
using FloatFoo = Foo<float, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f>; // specify default arguments when defining type
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2QTg1qZAgDX8XBMu)

BTW: Note that `float` can't be used as non-type template parameter before C++20.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried this before and failed in C++17. It works in C++20, but not in C++17 :-(.  I think it's because template parameters can only be very "simple" types.

Comment: @JoaoTavora Yes.. `float`s can't be used as non-type template argument before C++20. `int`s are fine.

Comment: Actually, the type I was looking for in my actual use was an enum class, and this works fine with it.  I wonder if c++20 can now support any constexpr-contructible type...

Comment: @JoaoTavora Yes, since C++20 any [literal class type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) could be used as [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter).